# Big Sorting: How are same-length strings sorted using lambda with key?

Tags: python, lambda, key

Here is my code :

```
def SortingBigIntegers(arr):
    arr.sort(key = lambda x: (len(x), x))

arr = ["54", "724523015759812365462",
        "870112101220845", "8723","6","9","3"]

SortingBigIntegers(arr)

print " ".join(arr)
```

How are same length strings sorted in this code?

Comment: First on the length, then lexicographically.

Comment: Why do you even need this, provided that Python integers can be arbitrarily large?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `key` is:

```
lambda x: (len(x), x)
```

So that means it is converted to a tuple. A tuple is sorted **first by first element, then by second element**. So in case the *length* of the two strings is equal, it will sort the strings by string. Strings are in Python sorted ***lexicographically***. In case the strings are integers (no decimal dot, and **no leading zeros**, etc.) and these have the same length, then they are sorted like we would sort them *numerically*.

In case the values are still the **same on both criteria**, the order will be the same as the **original order**: sorting in Python is *stable*.

That being said, in [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x), **`int`s can handle arbitrary size**. So you do not have to use strings, you can simply use `int`s.

Comment: Except that it fails for integers padded with zeros, f.e. `['01', '90', '9']` -> `['9', '01', '90']`. Also, `long` in Python2 is equivalent of `int` in Python3.

Comment: @randomir: thanks. That was indeed a case I did not take into account.

Answer (score 2):

In the function `SortingBigIntegers(arr, n)` , you have used `n` but you pass only `arr` . So, you should avoid this `n`.

Then follow this process :

```
def SortingBigIntegers(arr):
  arr.sort(key=lambda x: (len(x), x))


arr = ["54", "724523015759812365462","870112101220845", "8723", "6", "9", "3"]

SortingBigIntegers(arr)

print(" ".join(arr))
```

---

Output :

```
3 6 9 54 8723 870112101220845 724523015759812365462
```